# single command to `mv`/rename/move a file and set the user, group & permissions?

Tags: command-line, files, cp, mv

I can copy a file with `cp`. But with [`install`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/coreutils/install.1.en.html) I can copy a file, and set the owner, group and permissions on the new destination file, which is useful.

With `mv`, I can rename/move a file, which (if it's the same fs) is quicker than `cp`. Is there a one-liner / single command that will move/rename a file *and* allow me to set the user, group & permissions like `install` does? I can't see (in the `install` manpage) any `--rename-instead-of-copy` option

Comment: Is it the "single-command-ness" of the operation that is the issue? In that case, just create a shell function that runs `mv` and `chmod`.

Comment: Do you just need it for convenience or for some other reason? The usual solution would probably be something like `chown ... && chmod ... && mv ...`, which would even work to atomically put the file in place so it wouldn't be visible there with the wrong permissions. (assuming the move happens within the same filesystem).